# How can I get an eclipse project to reference source jars from maven local repository in a shared project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm currently working on a large shared project consisting of many smaller sub-projects. Recently the team migrated the build system to maven, however we currently have no source/javadoc information showing up in the eclipse editor for any of our referenced libraries.

I've been looking into a solution and gotten pretty far, with the maven dependency plugin I was able to copy source jars from my maven local repository into a shared folder one level above the sub-projects. I then used a linked folder in the sub-projects to reference the shared source jars folder. Finally I referenced the local linked folder from the .classpath files of each sub-project. This could all be done in a relative manner by making use of various variables.

I'm wondering now, if there's an even better way to do it. If I can create a linked folder in each project that goes straight to the maven local repository then I can eliminate the need to create an extra copy of all the source jars.

So far I have been unable to figure out a way to do this without specifying an absolute path, or making assumptions about the location of the maven local repository relative to the workspace directory (or something similar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do any of this.

If you use a jar as a `<dependency>` in Maven, then Eclipse automatically finds the `x-sources.jar` that lies next to the dependency.

So if you build a project with attached `sources` jar and then use it in another Maven project, the `sources` jar is found without further configuration.

Comment: I was rather surprised myself that this didn't just work out of the box, but it's definitely not happening for us. If I expand the 'maven dependencies' section of the project and double-click a class file in there I see sources/javadocs. If I reference that same class in code, I see 'this jar has no sources attached' message when I mouse-over it. Maybe I should ask a different question?

Comment: I think I see the problem, all of our maven dependencies are duplicated in a lib folder and included in the build path as loose jar files (which have no sources attached). Removing the extra lib jars gets source info/javadocs working and breaks the eclipse plugin manifest file. We obviously botched something in our efforts to merge maven with eclipse plugin projects and OSGI. Going to mark this as the answer and see if I can fix the project setup.